# Error declaring variable php

Tags: php

I want to Declaring variable

and I get error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'book' (T_STRING)

mycode

```
$filters = "library&loc=local,scope:("book")&loc=local,scope:("book2")....";
$path = "http://xxxxx/place/search/institution=".$filters."";
```

in line `$filters=.....` is error

and I don't want to change `"..."` to `'...'` because my result is change

Comment: Look at the highlighting. You'll need to escape the quotes if you don't want to change to singlequotes, making it `...scope:(\"book\")&...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes:

```
$filters = "library&loc=local,scope:(\"book\")&loc=local,scope:(\"book2\")....";
```

Alternatively, you can use single quotes for the entire string:

```
$filters = 'library&loc=local,scope:("book")&loc=local,scope:("book2")....';
```

Both of these result in the same string which is `library&loc=local,scope:("book")&loc=local,scope:("book2")....`

Answer (score 1):

You are using double quotes in the variable wich caused the error. You need to escape these quotes for example:

```
scope:(\"book\")
```

Or use single quotes:

```
scope:('book')
```

Same for book2.

I hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

@ARR.s use \before " like \" try below one:

```
<?php
$filters = "library&loc=local,scope:(\"book\")&loc=local,scope:(\"book2\")....";
$path = "http://xxxxx/place/search/institution=".$filters."";
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it. Use single quotes at the start and end of your string:

```
$filters = 'library&loc=local,scope:("book")&loc=local,scope:("book2")....';
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong the double quotes:

```
$filters = "library&loc=local,scope:("book")&loc=local,scope:("book2")....";
```

If you want to use double quotes inside a string declared using double quotes you have to scape them:

```
$filters = "library&loc=local,scope:(\"book\")&loc=local,scope:(\"book2\")....";
```

Anyway, the difference between using double and single quotes in php is that double quotes are evaluated, in your case you're not evaluating anything, so you can do this (and is a little faster becouse php doesn't have to evaluate the string)

```
$filters = 'library&loc=local,scope:("book")&loc=local,scope:("book2")....';
```

I recommend you to read the [php strings documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) to understand the difference between double quoted and single quoted strings and how string evaluation works